# Differences between two datasource options in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

We have two datasources in GeoServer for SQL Server.  What is the difference between them?

```
 Microsoft SQL Server - Microsoft SQL Server
 Microsoft SQL Server (JNDI) - Microsoft SQL Server (JNDI)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One uses JDBC and the other uses JNDI to connect to the database. If you don't know what that means then you want the first one.